# Springdoc configUrl behind api gateway

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have springdoc swagger ui up and running with a spring cloud gateway route /myapi. So when I hit the url

```
https://myhost.com/myapi
```

it redirects me to a url

```
https://myhost.com/myapi/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/swagger-config.json
```

I have below code in my application.yml file

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /
    configUrl: /swagger-config.json
```

and I have set the below property as well

```
server.forward-headers-strategy: framework
```

My question is what else do I need to do in order to get the redirected url to also include the API gateway route in the config URL? Basically I want the redirected url to be

```
https://myhost.com/myapi/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/myapi/swagger-config.json
```

and **NOT**

```
https://myhost.com/myapi/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/swagger-config.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a response from one of the contributors of the project on github (https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1144). It all works fine if we use the default springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl instead of specifying it explicitly.